# Unexpected GC behavior?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, .net-core-3.1

I'm writing a program that deals with a bunch (5000+) XML files, deserializing them and writing new XML files (1 for each) from their data, through async calls to a XmlWriter instance.

I noticed my program was garbage collecting twice (or more) per seconds.

Over 10 seconds:
[image]

Over 4 seconds:
[image]

So I wanted to see what I had in memory, and use [gcdump](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/collecting-and-analyzing-memory-dumps/) which, when called, performs a Gen 2 garbage collection.

After the aforementioned GC call, I no longer get any kind of automatic garbage collection until the end of the program, as I hoped it would be originally.

You can see the collections disappearing in the middle, that's when I called gcdump:
[image]

Is that a normal behavior for the GC?

I assume that around the start of a program, I'm creating an object on the heap that's taking most of the allocated space, so the GC has to be called very often; but why isn't this object automatically disposed? Why do I have to manually call the GC (through gcdump) for it to get disposed?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Which .NET version are you using, is it .NET Core or just .NET Framework? Do you have any specific config for gc, like `server` or `workstation` mode?

Comment: .NET Core 3.1, sorry. No specific config.